# creating C# code to get the value from json file

Tags: asp.net, json, api, integration

I have developed one *online bus seat booking project*, here I am using the API for each operation.

One operation had to write the information in `.xml` file now which they have changed to `.json`. Already I have got the value from `.xml`, but I didn't know how to get the value from `.json`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon type of method you are using. As far as they are `GET` you can get value from `Request.QueryString["Key"]` and if the method type is of `POST` then you can get those from `Request.Form["key"]`.
To return the result in Json format you can either use `.Net 3.0 System.Web.script.Serialization` namespace which contains Class for converting object to json data `JavaScriptSerializer` or you can use some third party dll such as `JSON.NET` One that fall in my favorite list while dealing with jSon data.